# Permission denied when I am trying to add Julia to path in MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal

I have installed Julia 1.7 on my macOS and because I cannot call it directly from the terminal, I want to add it to the path, for this aim, I am using the following command

```
ln -s /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
```

The result is however permission denied.

Does anybody have a solution?

Cheers

Comment: You have to use the root user or append your command with `sudo`, see [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012) or [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278427/when-to-use-sudo-in-macos)

Comment: Does `open -a Julia-1.7` work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately No.

Comment: You need to _prepend_ your command with sudo (and it will prompt you for your password):  
`sudo ln -s /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia`

Answer (score 2):

I also installed Julia 1.7 on my macOS but could NOT call it directly from the terminal.  I found `/usr/local/bin` that the symbolic link was pointing the julia folder:

`lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   52 Apr  5 17:25 julia -> /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia`

and not to the actual julia binary file.  (By the way, in the `/Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia` folder, I also found an existing symbolic link `julia -> /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia`, but I am unsure if this was working.)

So I did this update:

```sh
% cd /usr/local/bin
% sudo rm -i julia
remove julia? y
```

to remove the existing link, then recreated a link to the julia file (not, as previous, the julia folder):

```sh
% sudo ln -s /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
```

which shows:

```sh
% ls -l
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  62 May 19 10:53 julia -> /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia
```

and now I CAN call Julia 1.7 on my macOS directly from my terminal, as desired:

```sh
% julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.7.2 (2022-02-06)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  HEAD/bf53498635 (fork: 461 commits, 344 days) 
|__/                   |

julia>
```

Answer (score 0):

"""If you want to launch Julia from the command line, first open a new terminal window, then run the following snippet from your shell (e.g., using the Terminal app, not inside the Julia prompt)."""

`sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/julia sudo ln -s /Applications/Julia-1.8.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia`

https://julialang.org/downloads/platform/#macos